# Where to find the various cargo hold dimensions and volumes of transport aircraft, such as the A330-300?

Tags: cargo, datasets, airbus-a330

What are the dimensions of the cargo hold on the Airbus A330-300? (In order to check the usable space for containers or baggage.)

I'm looking for the internal dimensions of the hold with its subsections in the Airbus A330-300, i.e. length, width and height. What are they? This is in order to understand how much space there is and and how it's divided for standard containers or for baggage in bulk configuration.
I'm looking the value of volumes of the parts of the hold, too.

Comment: Where did you look yourself and what information was lacking?

Answer (score 7):

The [relevant] dimensions of the cargo compartments are published by the manufacturers. For all Airbus planes, visit: [Airbus / Airport and Maintenance Planning](http://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html). You can also search for other manufacturers.

For the requested number of [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device#ULD_capacity), here they are for the A330-300/900 (no need for the volume as the containers are standardized):

[image]

The documents also include the locations of cargo doors.

Comment: Thank you ymb1. It's already useful. But till now I haven't found the dimensions in the other directions like heights and widths.

Comment: @d.pensopositivo I suspect what you're looking for is whatever Airbus calls its equivalent to Boeing's Weight and Balance Control and Loading manuals. I did a Google search for "Airbus A-330 weight and balance control and loading manual" and came up with http://www.maletindevuelo.com/uploads/2/5/4/2/25428265/a330f_wbm.pdf which is for the -200. If the cross-sectional area of the -200 and the -300 are the same, that manual will suffice. It looks like what you want starts around page 1-10-60-20. It appears Airbus calls their equivalent manuals simply Weight and Balance Manual.

Comment: Excellent find @Terry - that should be an answer ;)

Comment: Thank you: What I'm looking for is the widths and height of the.... "room" inside (cargo hold) you can see, for example, in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kb7GsrJeq0

Comment: I need also a reference with volumes of hold.

Answer (score 1):

As for the widths, they are shown in [this document from Air China](http://www.airchinacargo.com/en/index.php?section=0-0149-0155-0176-0266)

[image]

---

[image]

<sup>source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Airbus_A300_cross_section.jpg/220px-Airbus_A300_cross_section.jpg)</sup>

They make the holds to fit the standard containers. They fit fairly tight but there's a little room around them.

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.searates.com/design/images/uld/ld3.jpg)</sup>

The outside height of an LD3 is 162.6 cm. If you look at the top diagram, on the right you see they have that marked (as 163 cm), therefore 171 is the height of the hold itself. There is 8cm of clearance above. On the left, PAG and PMC are pallets, or "cookie sheets". You stack whatever you need on them and cover it with a net, so 171cm would be the limit to how high you can load it so that it fits into the hold, except that the document lists the door on the front cargo hold to be 170cm and the aft to be 168 cm. So whatever you stack on a pallet has to fit through the door.

The bulk cargo hold is an irregular shape, so exact dimensions won't be given. But that Air China document indicates that they are 511cm deep and have a volume of 19.7 cubic meters.

Comment: Thank you TomMcW; finally, it's something with measures I'm looking for, i.e. internal of hold; only here it seems to me what we are seeing in this figure measured "171 cm" is not refered to cargo hold too, or I'm an in error and it's height of internal of structure.... ???

Comment: I'm looking a reference with value of volumes of forward and aft cargo hold, too

Comment: @d.pensopositivo I would guess that the 171cm dimension is the height of the door, while the max height of cargo (including a pallet, if it's on one) would be 163cm. Terry gave you [some search terms](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43952/where-to-find-the-various-cargo-hold-dimensions-and-volumes-of-transport-aircraf#comment113946_43967) on his comment on [ymb1's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43967/5517) that may well get you all the details you're after, since we don't seem to be able to get them specific enough for you.

Comment: Edited for clarification

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for pointing out the door. That limits things by a few more cm